# How do I get my Data Driven Pages Inset Map to center the grid featured?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cartography, data-driven-pages, geocoding

I'm doing data driven pages manually. I had this working out just fine but I must have changed the settings and can't figure out how to get the locator map to follow the grid featured.

Comment: Click on reference frame, go to extent indicator

Comment: @felexIP that's not really doing what I want. I need the locator map to follow the current grid and stay centered. when I click next on the the DDP  the locator map is not zooming in and centering on the current grid.

Comment: Is correct (the one with pages) dataframe active?

Comment: @FelixIP Maybe I'm not explaining my question right. The locator map is highlighting the correct grid but the locator map is not centering the grid when I move through the DDPs.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: so I can get the either the main data frame to center the correct grid or the locator map to center the correct grid by selecting it from the drop down from set up data driven pages but not both.

Comment: Yes.               It is correct statement

Comment: so the way you had it originally set up the inset map was automatically centering on the extent indicator every time you flipped to the next data driven page?

Comment: In the data frame extent have you selected other data frame?  http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/02/02/creating-dynamic-locator-maps-and-adding-page-effects-to-your-data-driven-pages/

Comment: @johns Through your article I found my solution. I had to go to data frame properties and click on the data frame tab, under extent, the first drop down, i had to choose other data frame. Then the locator map followed the main data frame.

Comment: @johns this is a feature I had no clue about. If you post as answer, I upvote it

Answer (score 4):

@johns Through your article I found my solution. I had to go to data frame properties and click on the data frame tab, under extent, the first drop down, i had to choose other data frame. Then the locator map followed the main data frame.

Comment: That's actually a pretty neat solution, I'll have to try it out more later!